# Continuously update SQL Server database using Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update a SQL Server database using Excel files. I followed right click database, Tasks, Import data method. It worked fine.

I have to update this database daily. But I can't use same Excel sheet for the update (I use same Excel format every day. First 3500-4000 rows need to update to end of the database table).

I can't copy day-wise data into single Excel sheet and update, because of the row limitation in Excel. I get 3500-4000 rows per day (1,048,576/3500 = 299 in 299 days, the Excel will be full), so I can't keep a single Excel file.

Comment: Stop putting all the data in one Excel file... If you have a daily file, have a daily file with the data for *that* day, and *that* day only.

Comment: Do you want to `UPDATE` the database, or `INSERT` rows into the database?

Comment: yes.how can I update daily file data  to last day last row onwards

Comment: i want copy excel data to sql data base day by day.thing is i use same format but i cant maintain  data as a single excel file.first 3500 rows in daily excel files need to upload to sql data base day by day

Comment: @larnu.Yes thats I want.But when I import data using task-importdata method second time onwards its overwriting the existitng data.Thats my issue.I want keep data which is upload with 1st day file.and  need to upload 2ns day file data from 1st day last row onwards.then need to add 3rd day data.like that